# pass PHP variable from form handling generated json to javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm learning PHP and Javascript. I have this little extraction project reading json from a URL. My form serves for building the URL from user inputting a keyword.

I want to output the JSON parsed with specific fields when it works and a simple message when there is no results.

But I can't get pass sending back the JSON Php object i get to my html as a javascript variable then I could use (JSON.parse(myJSvar))

Ajax is where i get stuck. My code above doesn't seem to respond using $.post to ('button").click, neither when I tried to give it an id and call by this id. Perhaps the following should be in another php and have an include or require to existing php page above :

```
 $newSearch= new ProgSearch();
 $found= json_encode($newSearch->search($search_string));

 echo $found; // json expected
```

So that *if i am correct use that shorter one in ajax call* to get the json output.

I tried some tutorial using Ajax but nothing got return so here's my original+edited code that process the form data into a url and parse it to retrieve json response in PHP.

**extract.php**

```
<?php

class ProgSearch {
  public $search_string;

  public function __construct() {
    if(isset($_POST["searchString"]))
    {
      $this->search_string= $_POST["searchString"];
    }
  }

  static function curl_helper($url){ // returns JSON
      $cURL = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
      curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Accept: application/json'));

      $json = curl_exec($cURL);
      curl_close($cURL);

      return $json;
    }

  public function search($url){
    $string= $this->search_string;
    $url= "http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/programmes/a-z/by/".$string."/current.json";

    $json= self::curl_helper($url);
    $results=json_decode($json, true);

   return $results;
  }

}
 // Run the class!
    $newSearch= new ProgSearch();
    $found= json_encode($newSearch->search($search_string));

    echo $found; // json expected

?>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Prog extractor</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search_box">
    <form action="extract.php" method="POST">
        Your search: <input type="text" name="searchString" /><br>
        amongst programmes on BBC Radio.
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="results">
    // placeholder
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxFunction.js"></script>
```

**ajaxFunction.js**

> ```
> $("button").click(function(){
>  var search= $('#search').val();
>
>     $.post('extract.php', { search: search }, function(data){
>       success:function(data){
>         $.('#results').html(data);
>       },
>       error:function(){
>         $.('#results').html("Sorry it's a failure");
>       }
>   });
>
> });
> ```

Comment: unless you show what you've got (your code), we can't help.

Comment: trying to embed it now

Comment: damn i got this problem too

Comment: Provide more details while asking questions. We could not assume your work.

Comment: @Ashok_Karale just added code in links above. I'm having trouble getting the variable from php to javascript accessible. Also I had been trying this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EHbBHm5l4g adapted of course but nothing showed in my #results div when trying to retrieve $programmefound from extract.php

Comment: You would like to check if you variable '$programmefound' does contain a value. If it does, then you might want to console.log on ajax side.

Comment: Do you get a result when submitting the form (as a first step)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external links (or pictures... yes, some people do that). That way questions don't break when third-party sites do.

Comment: @Jeff yes for instance with an example i get this like following that url  http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/programmes/a-z/by/chris/current.json

Comment: you get this:  - like nothing? with a valid search string (I tried 'test' and got a json from bbc)?

Comment: yes maybe retrieval doesn't need to be PHP just the variable string and then do read json from the url perhaps. Form is building the url

Comment: but i guess the point of ajax is provide output for failure as well

Comment: so it seems, that til now everything is working, you "just" need to change it to an ajax request rather then a form submit. Please try that and come back if you have troubles with that. Since there is no ajax function yet we cannot help any further I'm afraid.